# For Statement error from updating to Xcode 7.3

Tags: swift, for-loop, xcode7

I just updated Xcode to 7.3 and with Swift 3 looming there are some changes to the for statements. This is the error I am getting:

```
var i: CGFloat

        let totalNumberofCircles : CGFloat  = CGFloat(items.count) //items.count

        for i = -(totalNumberofCircles / 2); i < (totalNumberofCircles / 2); i += 1 {

}
```

**

> Error : C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version of Swift.

**

Anyone having the same error and ideas on how I can re-write the for statement to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2-2

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with :

```
for i in -(totalNumberofCircles / 2)..<(totalNumberofCircles / 2) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift. this is warning message not error message and error is coming because i is type of CGFloat.

```
  let totalNumberofCircles = items.count //items.count, it must be Int

  let totalNumberofCircles : CGFloat  = CGFloat(items.count)

 for i  in -(totalNumberofCircles/2)..<(totalNumberofCircles/2) {

 }
```